# US Citizen flying to Nicaragua without defined end date or visa

Tags: visas, airlines, us-citizens, long-term

My wife and I are planning on doing some long-term travel in Central/South America, starting in Nicaragua. We will be in Nicaragua for about 4-6 weeks, but want to maintain flexibility on both the exact length of our stay and our next destination.

I know that US Citizens (both of us) are not required to have a Nicaraguan visa for stays < 90 days, but the airlines from which we have tried to buy a flight ticket are requiring either a visa or proof of departure from Nicaragua.

Do I really need to book our departure this far ahead of time? Is there any other information here that I'm missing? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can always buy a refundable ticket, and refund it after you've arrived.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issues 2 years ago or so, not sure if it still works, but make a free reservation at COPA airlines, you will have 48 hours to pay it later. You got the idea